# Replacing newline in multiline textbox with <br/>

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to use a multiline textbox to insert text into a table which is displayed as html.  I want to with javascript take the text inside of the textbox and find where the user pressed enter and place "`<br/>`" in that position so when the text is displayed it will show line break.  Any ideas on how I could do this?

I tried something like this but it did not work.

```
var text = document.getElementById("announcementid").value;


            var newtext = text.replace("\n", "<br/>");

            text = newtext;
```

Comment: Just to note, this kind of processing should be done server-side and not client-side with javascript. (Assuming it's stored, in some fashion, on the server).

Comment: @Brad This statement is not necessarily true. There are several reasons why such processing should be done client-side...

Answer (score 3):

The `newtext` variable ends up being a *copy* of the original string from your `announcementid` element.  Thus, you'll need to *re*-set the `value` property on the original document element:

```
  var text = document.getElementById("announcementid").value;
  var newtext = text.replace(/\n/g, "<br />");
  document.getElementById("announcementid").value = newtext;
```

Also, as Konstantin pointed out, the `replace()` function in Javascript will just replace the first instance unless you pass in a global regular expression.

[Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/UjwHJ/)

Answer (score 0):

Text is a primitive so it would not replace the value. Use a regular expression to globally replace instead of replacing just the first instance:

```
var text = document.getElementById("announcementid").value;
var newtext = text.replace(/\n/g, "<br />");
document.getElementById("announcementid").value = newtext;
```

Comment: @BradChristie No need, because new line is treated simply like another character. This would work under all browsers.